# What's the different between clone method and assign the instance to another directly

Tags: c#, clone

I want to know, if I have a class named Test, what's the difference below

```
Test test = new Test();
Test newTest = test;
Test newTest2 = test.Clone();
```

What's the different between newTest and newTest2?
Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the instance, if `Test` is a class, you're actually copying the reference, but `test` and `newTest` will both point to the same instance in memory.

This means that both variables point to the same object:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.Foo = 24;
Test newTest = test;
newTest.Foo = 42;
Console.WriteLine(test.Foo); // Prints 42!
```

`Clone()`, on the other hand, typically is used to indicate a copy of the object itself, which means that `test` and `newTest2` would point to different objects, so the above wouldn't happen.

Note that, if test is a `struct` (value type), then a direct assignment is effectively a full (shallow) copy of the object, by value.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the distinction, one must first understand what an object reference is.  Since the term "reference" is used to refer to a number of different concepts, I like the term "Object ID".  To use an automotive analogy, an object ID is a slip of paper with a car's VIN on it.  If you hand the paint shop a piece of paper with "VIN ZX357" written on it and ask the shop to paint it blue, the shop won't paint the slip of paper blue, but rather they will find the car with that VIN number and paint that car blue.

If one has a variable `Wuzzle` of type `Car` (which is reference type) that happens to hold "VIN ZX357", and another variable `Fuzzle`, and one says `Fuzzle = Wuzzle`, then `Fuzzle` will--like `Wuzzle` hold "VIN ZX357".  There will still be one car.  One will just have two slips of paper, both of which hold the same VIN, and thus refer to the same car.  A statement like `Wuzzle.Color=Purple` will cause the car whose VIN is ZX357to be painted purple.  A request to examine `Fuzzle.Color` will look at car ZX357and report that it's purple.

If instead of saying `Fuzzle = Wuzzle`, one had said `Fuzzle = (Car)(Wuzzle.Clone())`, the effect would be to create a new car that was just like VIN ZX357, except that it would have a different VIN number (e.g. QL793) and `Fuzzle` would hold the new VIN, not 3941QXY5).  Saying `Wuzzle.Color = Orange` would then paint car 3941QXY5 orange, but it wouldn't affect car QL793.

Variables of interface type are treated just like any other reference type.  One could substitute `IColorizable` for `Car` and the behavior would be exactly the same.

It's important to note that `ICloneable` isn't a very good interface; a much better interface is `ICloneable<T>` which returns an object of type `T`.  There are two big advantages to this interface:

1. With `ICloneable`, it's necessary to typecast the return type to the type of object one wants.  This is a bit ugly.  `ICloneable<T>` eliminates this requirement.
2. With `ICloneable`, there can be some ambiguity as to which object references within an object should be copied as-is to the clone, and which ones should themselves be cloned.  The ambiguity isn't nearly as bad as some people make it out to be, but the generic `ICloneable<T>` can make it a little clearer.  For example, if one has an object `CloneableSortedList<T>`, then calling `ICloneable<CloneableSortedList<T>.Clone()` on that list should return a new `CloneableSortedList` which contains the same references to type T as the original one did.  By contrast, if one has a `CloneableSortedUserList`, calling `ICloneable<CloneableSortedUserList>` should return a new `CloneableSortedUserList` which will regard the users' attributes, rather than the user object references, as values (thus copying them if they are mutable).

Comment: Whats the difference between 
Car c=new Car 
      and
 d= (Car)(c.Clone())

Comment: @Charlie: Cloning a default-value instance would likely yield an instance very much like what the default constructor would return.  Would you expect anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Assignment **copies only the reference**, not the object itself.

If your class implements [`IClonable.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), it can be written to perform a **deep copy** operation, that is, to return a newly allocated object of the same type, the fields of which are copies of the original. It's an interesting question what to do when a field is a reference type: copy the reference, or deep-copy the referenced object? For example, [`Object.MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) copies only the reference (this is called a **shallow copy**), but if you choose to implement [`IClonable.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), then you can decide this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test newTest = test;
```

Since Test is a reference type (class), `newTest` now references the same object as `test`. If you change the object `test` references, that will be reflected in `newTest` since they both reference to the same object.

```
Test newTest2 = test.Clone();
```

Assuming `Clone()` is returning a *new* instance and does a deep copy (it truly depends on your implementation) , `newTest2` is referring to a completely separate object, any changes in `test` won't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

New test actually points to the same object in memory as test, so modifying newTest changes test. newTest2 is actually a copy of test.